# Can we display KML data on Google maps using Mapkit framework on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

I have a requirement wherein I have to show some maps and some data corresponding to that maps. The problem is that the backend server uses MapXtreme to generate GIS data, and there is no MapX client for iOS devices. The server people tell me that they can send me KML files for generating the maps.

Is there any way to use KML files to display geographic information on Google maps using Mapkit framework?

EDIT: 
I have gone through a similar question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617782/can-i-use-my-own-tiles-in-mapkit-instead-of-googles) link. In one of the answer vy32 shared a link of Google earth's tutorial site to create a KML file. He also argues that it can be used in Mapkit. The question remains ...how de we do it??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality for this.  Apple provide [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) that parses a subset of KML that you can use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim. I am going to try out this approach now :D

Answer (score 0):

Google web can take a `kml` URL in place of a street address.Have you considered using `webkit` to show Google web map?
 
**Note:** The `kml` url can be a CGI query into a database.